# os.makedirs doesn't understand "~" in my path

Tags: python, path

I have a little problem with `~` in my paths.

This code example creates some directories called `~/some_dir` and do not understand that I wanted to create `some_dir` in my home directory.

```
my_dir = "~/some_dir"
if not os.path.exists(my_dir):
    os.makedirs(my_dir)
```

Note this is on a Linux-based system.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

You need to expand the tilde manually:

```
my_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/some_dir')
```

Answer (score 96):

The conversion of `~/some_dir` to `$HOME/some_dir` is called [tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion) and is a common user interface feature. The file system does not know anything about it.

In Python, this feature is implemented by [os.path.expanduser](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
my_dir = os.path.expanduser("~/some_dir")
```

Comment: Indeed, and it is perfectly valid to have a file or directory named `~`. So the shell home shortcut is ambiguous and best avoided if you can.

Comment: Note that one CAN access a file/dir named "~" in the current directory even when tilde expansion is occuring, using the "./~" notation. That works because ~ expansion only occurs at the start of a file name.

It's also a convenient hack for file names starting with "-" or other characters that are treated specially by command line interfaces.

You could tell I have probably done way too much shell script hacking.

Comment: `The file system does not know anything about it.` +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what is the more pythonic (and platform-independent) syntax convention for paths in user's home dir? Is it  `$HOME/some_dir` instead of the tilde, as in your example?

Answer (score 17):

That's probably because Python is not Bash and doesn't follow same conventions. You may use this:

```
homedir = os.path.expanduser('~')
```