# Best practice to pass multiple paths as command line argument accounting for paths with spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

## Background

The Python module I'm writing has some functionalities available from command line interface via `python -m fun_module -p ....` argument `-p`, `--path` takes multiple paths. Presently I'm defining this argument in the following manner:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="FunProg", add_help=True)
parser.add_argument(
    "-p",
    "--path",
    type=utils.dir_path,
    nargs="+",
    help="Start path(s) used to conduct the search. Multiple paths should be separated with spaces.",
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

### `dir_path` function available via `utils.py` file

```
import os

def dir_path(str_path):
    if os.path.isdir(str_path):
        return str_path
    else:
        raise NotADirectoryError(str_path)
```

### `main` method

```
def main(args):
    for iarg in args.path:
        print("Searching path: " + iarg)
```

## Problem

Handling multiple paths separated with spaces and surrounded with inverted commas doesn't return the desired results.

### Desired output

```
python -m fun_module -p ~/Documents ~/Downloads/
Searching path: /Users/thisuser/Documents
Searching path: /Users/thisuser/Downloads/

python -m fun_module -p '~/Documents' '~/Downloads/'
Searching path: /Users/thisuser/Documents
Searching path: /Users/thisuser/Downloads/

python -m fun_module -p "~/Documents" "~/Downloads/"
Searching path: /Users/thisuser/Documents
Searching path: /Users/thisuser/Downloads/
```

### Error:

```
python -m fun_module -p '~/Documents' '~/Downloads/'                          
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/thisuser/Dev/Python/FileLister/filelister/__main__.py", line 25, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 1818, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 1851, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 2060, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 2000, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 1912, in take_action
    argument_values = self._get_values(action, argument_strings)
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 2461, in _get_values
    value = [self._get_value(action, v) for v in arg_strings]
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 2461, in <listcomp>
    value = [self._get_value(action, v) for v in arg_strings]
  File "/Users/thisuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 2476, in _get_value
    result = type_func(arg_string)
  File "/Users/thisuser/Dev/Python/FileLister/filelister/utils.py", line 7, in dir_path
    raise NotADirectoryError(str_path)
NotADirectoryError: ~/Documents
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping your path string in `os.path.normpath(path_str)`. Look into this function, together with `os.path.abspath` and `os.path.relpath`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057045/pythons-os-makedirs-doesnt-understand-in-my-path) post help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was two folded:

1. As indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057045/pythons-os-makedirs-doesnt-understand-in-my-path) post, you need to use `os.path.expanduser` when using the `~`.
2. When your input contains quotes (`'` or `"`), the `os.path.expanduser` won't properly handle the input.

To solve the issues, first replace the quotes by empty strings. Using python 3.9 this can be done with:

```
for quote in ['"', "'"]:
    str_path = str_path.removeprefix(quote).removesuffix(quote)
```

otherwise you have to manually check and remove:

```
for quote in ['"', "'"]:
   if str_path.startswith(quote):
      str_path = str_path[1:-1]
```

And then you have to check for a tilde start:

```
if str_path.startswith('~'):
    str_path = os.path.expanduser(str_path)
```

Full code:

```
def dir_path(str_path: str):
    for quote in ['"', "'"]:
        if str_path.startswith(quote):
            str_path = str_path[1:-1]
    if str_path.startswith('~'):
        str_path = os.path.expanduser(str_path)
    if os.path.isdir(str_path):
        return str_path
    raise NotADirectoryError(str_path)
```

And testing with any of the following inputs will result in a full path:

```
python -m fun_module -p '~/Documents' '~/Downloads'
python -m fun_module -p "~/Documents" "~/Downloads"
python -m fun_module -p ~/Documents ~/Downloads
```