# How import multiple text files to one dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I found [here](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/how-to-import-data-from-multiple-text-files-in-python-c3956a878fe0) how to import multiple text files to one data frame. However, it gives an error. Files are with the names as footballseason1,footballseason2,footballseason3 ... (until footballseason5000)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import os, glob
os.chdir("~/Downloads/data")
filenames = [i for i in glob.glob("*.txt")]
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Downloads/data'

However, if I try to import one file, everything is working and the directory is found

```
df = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/data/footballseason1.txt", sep=",")
```

Could you help to fix the problem? and are there any ways to do it without changing directory and simply do all the steps using the path where all files are located?

Comment: When you read one file, you are reading a file with extension **txt** and when you read the folder you are reading extension **csv** and maybe you don't have any file

Comment: I also changed to **txt.** but the same error

Comment: what are your actual file types and where are the files stored?

Comment: all files are of `.txt` format and located in `"~/Downloads/data/"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `os` does not understand `~` by default, so it [needs to be expanded manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057072/13138364):

```py
filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/data/*.txt"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `list comprehension` and `pd.concat` like below

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i, sep=',') for i in glob.glob("~/Downloads/data/*.txt", recursive=True)])
```

Comment: I have an error: `No objects to concatenate`

Comment: try by adding recursive=True

Comment: now it says `name 'true' is not defined`.  I also tried in different way to see whether functions are working using code below, but again the error that directory does not exist

`import glob, os

os.chdir("~/Downloads/data")
for file in glob.glob("*/.txt", recursive = true):
print(file)  `

Comment: what does os.lisdir('~/Downloads/data') gives you

Answer (score 0):

Via pathlib ->

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
inp_path = Path("~/Downloads/data")
df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(txt_file, sep=',') for txt_file in inp_path.glob('*.txt')
])
```

With added check - >

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
inp_path = Path("~/Downloads/data")
if inp_path.exists():
    df = pd.concat([
        pd.read_csv(txt_file, sep=',') for txt_file in inp_path.glob('*.txt')
    ])
else:
    print('input dir doesn\'t exist please check path')
```

Answer (score -1):

Importing Data from Multiple files
Now let’s see how can we import data from multiple files from a specific directory. There are many ways to do so, but I personally believe this is an easier and simpler way to use and also to understand especially for beginners.
1)First, we are going to import the OS and glob libraries. We need them to navigate through different working directories and getting their paths.
import os
import glob
2) We also need to import the pandas library as we need to work with data frames.
import pandas as pd
3) Let’s change our working directory to the directory where we have all the data files.
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\HARISH\Path_for_our_files")
4) Now we need to create a for loop which iterates through all the .csv file in the current working directory
filenames = [i for i in glob.glob("*.csv")]

Comment: This answer is completely unrelated to the OP's problem. Please read questions carefully, and note that answers on SO are supposed to really answer the question asked.