# Why subprocess.call('ls ~/mnt', shell=True) works but os.path.exists('~/mnt') doesn't?

Tags: python

I am trying to access a path starting with ~/ in linux using python and its not working. Tried getting absolute path but that also is failing for ~/paths. What is the right way to handle ~/path in python?

```
mkdir ~/mnt
touch ~/mnt/test.txt
ls ~/mnt
```

Results:

```
test.txt
```

## python3

```
import os
import subprocess
print(os.path.exists('~/mnt'))
print(os.path.exists(os.path.abspath('~/mnt')))
subprocess.call('ls ~/mnt3', shell=True)
```

Results in,

```
False
False
test.txt
0
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Comment: `~` doesn't expand.

Comment: you don't need it on the last line though (where you call `ls`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057072/361842

Answer (score 0):

An easier way in Python 3, is with the builtin `pathlib` module:

```py
from pathlib import Path

# don't forget the `expanduser()` here
p = Path('~/.mnt').expanduser()

print(p.exists())  # true
print(p.absolute().exists())  # true

p2 = p / 'other_file'
print(str(p2))  # /Users/<user>/.mnt/other_file
```